# Does smartermail store the parsed email messages in a sql database I could access directly?

Tags: email

Does smartermail store the parsed email messages in a sql database I could access directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, Smartermail, certainly on my install, doesn't use a SQL database at all.  The mails are stored under the domain folder as separate files and indexed by custom grp and cfg files.

I'm sure the [Smartermail forums](http://www.smartertools.com/forums/) can provide a more comprehensive answer if you want to try there

Answer (score 1):

The way SmarterMail doesn't store it in database will make the life easier when it comes to a per domain migration. You will see this really save you a lot of hassle! If you would like to access to the email data directly, you could actually open up the grp file via a notepad and you should be able to see the content inside.